# Does anyone can help me with problems on to fill the elements of my matrix?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, math, matrix

I am with a problem in my Python Code. I am trying to fill a Matrix "A_control" with dimensions "2NGL x 2NGL", being NGL=2. But something is wrong and when I try to run my code the following mensage appears: "index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6".

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

The part of my code follows:

```
p=3; q=2;
        for p in range (p, (2*NGL-1)):
            A_control[p,0]=kt[i,j]/mt;
            A_control[p,1]=ct[i,j]/mt;
            for q in range (q, (2*NGL-1)):
                A_control[p,q]=-kt[i,j]/mt
                print(p,q)
                A_control[p,q+1]=-ct[i,j]/mt
                q=q+1
                p=p+2
            print(p,q)
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: why do you use the same variable for `q=2` and `for q in ... `? it makes some problems. And using `q=q+1` inside `for q in ...` is useless because `for q in...` will assign own value instead of `q=q+1`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.